# Builder not changed in aftertextchanged for edittext in fragment

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog, builder, textwatcher

How can I change my edittext after changed? Method works but edittext not change. Can I use setview in aftertextchanged? Alertdialog in fragment so it is difficult and I used this app crashed

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getContext());
        builder.setTitle("Lütfen tutar girin");

        final EditText input = new EditText(this.getContext());

        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
        builder.setView(input);
        input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                                         @Override
                                         public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                                         }

                                         @Override
                                         public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                                         }

                                         @Override
                                         public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                                             try {
                                                 if(s.length()>=4) {
                                                     s = new SpannableStringBuilder(Formatter(s.toString()));
                                                 }
                                             }catch (NumberFormatException e){

                                             }
                                         }
                                     });


                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", (dialog, which) -> {
                    String pin = input.getText().toString();
                    if (!pin.isEmpty()) {
                        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.container, new CardFragment((int) (Float.parseFloat(pin) * 100), operation))
                                .addToBackStack(null).commit();
                    } else {
                        showMessage("Lütfen Tutar Giriniz");
                    }

                });

        builder.show();
```

It's change the text field. Formatter:

```
 public  String Formatter(String rut) {
    String mString;
    if(rut.length()==4){
        mString = rut.substring(0,4)+",";
    }else if(rut.length()==5){
        mString = rut.substring(0,4)+","+rut.substring(3,4);
    }else
        mString = rut.substring(0,4)+","+rut.substring(3,5);
    return mString;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved with this:

```
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        try {
             input.removeTextChangedListener(this);
             if(s.length()>4){
             s = new SpannableStringBuilder( Formatter(s.toString()));
             input.setText(s);
          }
input.addTextChangedListener(this);
         } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                input.addTextChangedListener(this);
         }
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer after two days to indicate that the question has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

In your public void `afterTextChanged(Editable s)` method make changes to the Editable object instead don't assign a new object to the reference `s` e.g.

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if (s.length() < 4)
        s.append("abc");
}
```

This happens because the original text on the `EditText` comes from the object referenced by `s`, if you assign a new object to this reference it won't affect the original object hence it won't affect the text in the view.

Comment: what is append?  I used this and s not changed

Comment: can you post what changes you have made in the ```public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)```

Comment: append as the name suggests is used to add a string after the original string, eg:
```String s = "hello";
s.append("world");
print(s);```
output:- helloworld

Comment: @Override
                                         public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                                             try {
                                                 if(s.length()>=4){
                                                     s.append("try");
                                                 }

                                             }catch (NumberFormatException e){

                                             }
                                         }

Comment: Ok I think add only number because input type number. but length>4 so loop